# How to auto mount VMware Shared Folder on boot

Tags: mount, vmware, fstab

I want to automatically mount a VMware Shared Folder on boot in Ubuntu.

Currently, I'm using the following command manually each time:

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/"Ubuntu Shared Folder" /mnt/hgfs/"Ubuntu Shared Folder" -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```

I tried adding the following line to the end of **/etc/fstab**, but it doesn't work:

```
.host:/"Ubuntu Shared Folder" /mnt/hgfs/"Ubuntu Shared Folder" fuse.vmhgfs-fuse allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000 0 0
```

Is there something wrong with my approach, or is there a different method to achieve automatic mounting on boot?